# Chinese phones auto start app (notifications)

Tags: notifications, huawei, xiaomi

I have a question maybe some of you have dialed with this in your past.
Android based phones with Chinese launchers such as Xiaomi, Huawei, Meizu has 1 strange thing in common…
If you install on them not very famous app such as Signal for example, by default this app will not receive notifications - the only way to make the phone accept notifications is (in xiaomi for example) is to go to settings, security, auto start…
But there are apps like messenger, google allo, telegram that are white listed and receive notifications by default…
Attaching link with short explanation about it
So my question is how to enter list of those white listed apps that receive notifications by default, or are there any life hacks that you can do in order to receive notifications by default…

http://nine-faq.9folders.com/articles/8772-how-to-manage-autostart-service-on-the-xiaomi-devices

Signal app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.securesms&hl=en

So after making a research I’ve found that this feature is developed to block wakeups and notifications and make the battery last longer and there is not a way to bypass it. If there is, it's hard.

but how famous apps bypass it ? or how to enter a white list?

Answer (score 1):

Chinese phone manufacturer tend to place very strict restriction on app autostart due to the lack of google in China causing all sort of apps to start by themselves and no universal push notification channel also mean they have to use other service within apps themselves or other apps which would be detrimental to user experience and thus they all opt to limit them.

Perhaps manufacturer whitelisted some specific famous apps?

Comment: yes exactly - they whitelisted specific famous apps - such as facebook, whatsapp etc...but my app is not such a monster so im wondering how to enter this white list?

Comment: According to a Chinese thread on Xiaomi forum http://www.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=1838253 , they will consider whitelisting apps once they become really popular.